# Como aplicar un formato de cantidad numerica a un input

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Estoy intentando hacer una función que aplique cierto formato numérico a un input. A través de un onblur se requiere una función que aplique a una cantidad que puede ser escrita de la siguiente manera "  145151,65  " pueda formatearmela de la siguiente manera  "  145.151,65  " Actualmente del lado del js tengo esto:

```
function formatNumber(num) {
if (num == 'Infinity') return '&#x221e;';
console.log(num);
num = num.toString().replace(/\$|\,/g, '');
console.log(num);
num = num.toString().replace('.', '');
console.log(num);
num = num.toString().replace(',', '.');
console.log(num);
//if (isNaN(num))       num = "0";
sign = (num == (num = Math.abs(num)));
num = Math.floor(num * 100 + 0.50000000001);
cents = num % 100;
if (cents < 10)
    cents = "0" + cents;
num = Math.floor(num / 100).toString();
for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor((num.length - (1 + i)) / 3) ; i++)
    num = num.substring(0, num.length - (4 * i + 3)) + '.' + num.substring(num.length - (4 * i + 3));
return (((sign) ? '' : '-') + num );
```

}

Y del lado del html esto

```
<div class="col-md-4 form-group" style="margin-left:-30px">                                     
     <input id="input-sm" type="text" class="form-control col-sm-offset-1 numeros" ng-model="limiteSuperiorAct" id="limiteSuperiorActJD" placeholder="Limite Superior" onblur="this.value = formatNumber(this.value);">
```

Y el resultado que me da al escribir la cantidad cuando se activa el onblur es esto:"  14.515.165   ". Es decir que me tomo la parte decimal con si fuera un numero entero y posterior me la formateo. Si pudieran ayudarme gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

he pensado la siguiente solución, dado que la parte "entera" ya la tienes controlada, y que la parte decimal no la tienes que modificar, puedes cortar la cadena en dos con el siguiente código:

```
  var comma = num.split(',')[1];
  num = num.split(',')[0];
```

De esta forma, tu código sólo afectaría a la parte entera. Por último, he puesto la siguiente comprobación al final, para verificar que efectivamente el número tiene parte decimal:

```
var result = '';
  if (comma){
    result = ((sign) ? '' : '-') + num +','+comma;
  } else {
    result = ((sign) ? '' : '-') + num;
  }
return result;
```

En caso de no tenerla, tu código sólo afectaría a la parte entera.

Te dejo la prueba que he usado para que lo pruebes:

```js
function formatNumber(num) {
  var comma = num.split(',')[1];
  num = num.split(',')[0];
  console.log("Coma:"+comma);
if (num == 'Infinity') return '&#x221e;';
console.log(num);
num = num.toString().replace(/\$|\,/g, '');
console.log(num);
num = num.toString().replace('.', '');
console.log(num);
num = num.toString().replace(',', '.');
console.log(num);
//if (isNaN(num))       num = "0";
sign = (num == (num = Math.abs(num)));
num = Math.floor(num * 100 + 0.50000000001);
cents = num % 100;
if (cents < 10)
    cents = "0" + cents;
num = Math.floor(num / 100).toString();
for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor((num.length - (1 + i)) / 3) ; i++)
    num = num.substring(0, num.length - (4 * i + 3)) + '.' + num.substring(num.length - (4 * i + 3));
  var result = '';
  if (comma){
    result = ((sign) ? '' : '-') + num +','+comma;
  } else {
    result = ((sign) ? '' : '-') + num;
  }
return result;
}
```

```html
<input id="input-sm" type="text" id="limiteSuperiorActJD" placeholder="Limite Superior" onblur="this.value = formatNumber(this.value);">
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda.
Saludos.

Comment: El código me funciona muy bien cuando escribo la cantidad y se ejecuta el onblur. Pero sucede que si se sale del campo, se le da click sin modificar nada y hace un segundo onblur, se cambia la cantidad que inicial mente estaba.  Ejemplo    12345666,33  ---> Primer onblur    12.345.666,33 (perfecto), segundo onblur sin cambios    12.345.666,33  ---> 12.345,33 (aqui es donde ocurre el cambio que no se deberia dar). Pude observar que sucede cuando se salta a un tercer conjunto de miles, es decir cuando comienza la unidad de millón (1.000.000)

Comment: @AlejandroPereira el problema esta en `num = num.toString().replace('.', '');` esa linea solo esta cambiando el primer `.` que encuentra, dejando en tu ejemplo el string `12345.666` y mas adelante con el `Math.floor()` que devuelve un _integer_ todo lo que esta después del `.` se pierde. Solo cambia la primer linea que mencione por esta otra `num = num.toString().replace(/\./g, '');` y debería salir andando.

Answer (score -1):

Te dejo un ejemplo de como lo podrías hacer. No es el gran código, está comentado para que se entienda. Saludos!

```js
function toCurrency(string){
        return string.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
    }
    
 function check(obj)
 {
    //Reemplaxamos la coma por un punto y le asignamos presicion de 2 decimales.
     let val = parseFloat(obj.value.replace(",",".")).toFixed(2);
     
     //Aplicamos el formato deseado
     val = toCurrency(val);
     //Actualizamos el valor
     obj.value= val;

 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="" onblur="check(this)" placeholder="Ingrese un numero">
```